# Set the state of a menu item on shortcut press

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

A program has a menu bar, which has a menu, which has a menu item. The menu item is enabled or disabled depending on some circumstances. Checking of circumstances and enabling/disabling of the menu item is done when a user clicks on the menu that holds that menu item.

But, there is also a shortcut associated with that menu item. The shortcut functions only when the menu item is enabled.

How can we set the state of a menu item without clicking on the menu that holds it, when we want to use a shortcut?

Here is an example program that will hopefully make my question more clear:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

struct check_sensitivity
{
        GtkWidget *menuitem;
        GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
};

void sensitivity(GtkWidget *menu, struct check_sensitivity *sens)
{
        if (gtk_text_buffer_get_modified(sens->buffer))
                gtk_widget_set_sensitive(sens->menuitem, TRUE);
        else
                gtk_widget_set_sensitive(sens->menuitem, FALSE);
}

void menuitem_click(GtkWidget *menuitem, GtkTextBuffer *buffer)
{
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "", -1);
        gtk_text_buffer_set_modified(buffer, FALSE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

        struct check_sensitivity sens;

        GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

        GtkWidget *view = gtk_text_view_new();
        sens.buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view));

        GtkWidget *menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
        GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new();

        GtkAccelGroup *shortcuts = gtk_accel_group_new();
        gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), shortcuts);

        GtkWidget *menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Menu");
        gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(menuitem), menu);
        gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), menuitem);
        g_signal_connect(menuitem, "activate", G_CALLBACK(sensitivity), &sens);
        menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Clear");
        gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menuitem);
        gtk_widget_add_accelerator(menuitem, "activate", shortcuts, GDK_KEY_D, GDK_CONTROL_MASK, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
        sens.menuitem = menuitem;
        g_signal_connect(sens.menuitem, "activate", G_CALLBACK(menuitem_click), sens.buffer);

        GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

        gtk_widget_show_all(window);

        gtk_main();
}
```

In this program, the state of menu item "Clear" depends on that whether the buffer is modified or not. The state is, of course, set when the user clicks on the menu "Menu".

There is also a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> that does the same thing as clicking on "Clear". The shortcut works as it should depending on the state of the menu item, but what is wrong is the state of the menu item. Let me explain:

Since the menu item is (un)set when a user click on "Menu", to update the state of "Clear" before using a shortcut, a user must click on it. If the shortcut is used before updating of the state of the menu item, it may not be able to do its function when it should.

Here is what you can try: open the program and write something. Try clearing it with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>. You'll see that nothing happens even though it should, because the state of the menu item is not updated. If you click on "Menu", then try using the shortcut again, the text buffer will clear.

I'm just asking for a why to update the state when the shortcut is pressed as well. I tried a few ways that base on setting the state when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed (I can't check only for <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, I may have another shortcuts in a program), but all of them failed or produced bugs. One of those ways you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409104/key-release-event-not-triggered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a working method.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

struct check_sensitivity
{
        GtkWidget *menuitem;
        GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
};

void sensitivity(GtkWidget *menu, struct check_sensitivity *sens);

void check_sensitivity_on_ctrl(GtkWidget *window, GdkEventKey *key, struct check_sensitivity *sens)
{
    if(key->keyval == GDK_KEY_Control_L || key->keyval == GDK_KEY_Control_R)
    {
        sensitivity(NULL, sens);
    }
}

void sensitivity(GtkWidget *menu, struct check_sensitivity *sens)
{
        if (gtk_text_buffer_get_modified(sens->buffer))
                gtk_widget_set_sensitive(sens->menuitem, TRUE);
        else
                gtk_widget_set_sensitive(sens->menuitem, FALSE);
}

void menuitem_click(GtkWidget *menuitem, GtkTextBuffer *buffer)
{
        gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "", -1);
        gtk_text_buffer_set_modified(buffer, FALSE);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

        struct check_sensitivity sens;

        GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 400);
        g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

        GtkWidget *view = gtk_text_view_new();
        sens.buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(view));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_modified(sens.buffer, FALSE);

        GtkWidget *menubar = gtk_menu_bar_new();
        GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new();

        GtkAccelGroup *shortcuts = gtk_accel_group_new();
        gtk_window_add_accel_group(GTK_WINDOW(window), shortcuts);

        GtkWidget *menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Menu");
        gtk_menu_item_set_submenu(GTK_MENU_ITEM(menuitem), menu);
        gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menubar), menuitem);
        g_signal_connect(menuitem, "activate", G_CALLBACK(sensitivity), &sens);
        menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label("Clear");
        gtk_menu_shell_append(GTK_MENU_SHELL(menu), menuitem);
        gtk_widget_add_accelerator(menuitem, "activate", shortcuts, GDK_KEY_D, GDK_CONTROL_MASK, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
        sens.menuitem = menuitem;
        g_signal_connect(sens.menuitem, "activate", G_CALLBACK(menuitem_click), sens.buffer);
    g_signal_connect_after(window, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(check_sensitivity_on_ctrl), &sens);

        GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), menubar, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), view, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

        gtk_widget_show_all(window);

        gtk_main();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the menuitem sensitivity depending on if there is text in your textbuffer, connect to the textbuffer changed or modified-changed signal. Since I am not good at C, but normally use Python:

```
textbuffer.connect("changed", update_menuitem_sensitivity)
```

[changed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer-changed)

[modified-changed](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer-modified-changed)

Comment: I already know for that, but that won't do it in all my cases. I need something else.

Comment: Ok, so what do you need to do? Your question is something like "This doesn't work, and I don't know what I need, but make it work for me." Or that is how it appears to anybody viewing this question.

Comment: All I'm asking for is a way to update the menu items when a user presses a shortcut. I know how to update them normally, I just don't know how to call an update function properly that updates them when a user presses a shortcut. Signals won't work for all of my menu items (actually, I had to start all over again when I used to think they would).

Comment: Have you tried connecting to a `key-release-event`? And then update your menuitem from there based on all your requirements..

Comment: I'm not sure what is your idea... I tried [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409104/key-release-event-not-triggered?noredirect=1&lq=1) with `"key-release-event"`, but your idea is probably different? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Ok, we are going around in circles. I really don't know what you are trying to accomplish. The other question you gave obviously won't work. How about you edit your questions with something like "I am creating a text editor. When the user presses `Ctrl+D` I want to clear the text, if the text was changed." Instead, your question reads "I have a menuitem that is not sensitive. Help me make it sensitive when something changes, but it can only be sensitive when the user clicks menu." Your question contradicts itself.

Comment: I don't think my question contradicts itself. I'm not asking to make it (in)sensitive when something changes per se, I'm asking to make it (in)sensitive when a user clicks a menu that holds it or the shortcut is pressed. Only when (s)he does, the circumstances are checked and the state is set. I already know how to do it for menu, but not when the shortcut is pressed. I tried checking for circumstances and setting the sensitivity when I detect that a `Ctrl` is pressed because every shortcut starts with it. As for editing my question, `Ctrl-D` is just an example I gave and method that may work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180508/discussion-between-thegtknerd-and-hanlon).

Comment: for it may not work for all menu items. Some menu items, unlike those related to modified text which can be set using signals, are impossible (to my knowledge at least) to set when something changes because the circumstances on which their sensitivity depends can be checked only manually, i.e. not on the basis of signals. That's why the method I use sets the sensitivity when items is potentially about to be used (clicking on a menu that holds, and a failed attempt to check the circumstances upon pressing `Ctrl`).